# How to add non-Windows user account to TFS 2013 project's members

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-server-2012, tfs-2013

How can I add a non-Windows user to a Team Foundation Server 2013 team project?

I have tried but without luck, since I don't want to add a new user to the active directory each time I add a new member.

I have installed Team Foundation Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012. What I want is to add a new user (for example, username email@email.com, pass 12345) to an existing team project.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot. Every TFS users *is* a Windows user.

On a single server install, you have the option to use local users in addition to Active Directory user accounts, but I do not recommend it.

Comment: so,  what i can do in my case?

Comment: There are no such thing as "TFS users" or "non-Windows users" for TFS. You must always create a Windows user, be it from Active Directory or local to the machine (this latter works only for a single server/application tier)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a free Visual Studio Online account and move everything there. You can then add users by email and get them to create and manage their own MSA (Microsoft Account)